# Setting max build retention with Artifactory and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Artifactory with Jenkins to store builds, and I'm attempting to set a limit to the number of builds that are stored. I'm doing the following, but artifacts and builds are never being cleaned up. Any suggestions?

```
def uploadSpec = """{......}""" //Just setting pattern, target, props and regexp

def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
buildInfo.env.capture = true
buildInfo.retention maxBuilds: 10, maxDays: 30, deleteBuildArtifacts: true

server.upload(uploadSpec, buildInfo)
server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo)
```

Comment: Can you try running the [build retention pipeline example](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-pipeline-examples/vars-build-retention-example/Jenkinsfile)?

Comment: Isn't that what I'm more or less doing? :)

Comment: Which Artifactory version are you using ? 
I run the example and it works for me, I know it's more or less what you are doing but still can you create a new job and run the example?

Comment: I'm using Artifactory Version 5.2.0. It's rather difficult to use exactly what is written though, as I'm behind a firewall that won't let that through remotely

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Have you tried to check the permissions of the Artifactory account used to publish?
I think if it doesn't have proper (delete) permissions - it just silently ignores the retention.

Comment: I think the problem is actually that it's only supported on cloudbees? I read that somewhere AFAICR

Comment: I don't think Artifactory plugin in Jenkins has some restrictions related to cloudbees. Can you please share the link you've read ?